# AES encrypted database entry size

Tags: android, ios, database, encryption, aes

I am gonna use 256bit AES encrypted data on a mobile database.

My question is, is there a special factor to multiply the database field sizes?

Example:
Lets say I am allowing size 10 str, when its encrypted the size goes up about x2-x3 times.
So I should use at least size 25 str in the field.

Is there a special number I could multiply my normal field sizes to find out the minimum safe encrypted size?

Comment: Please provide more information about the mode of encryption and the encoding of the encrypted data that you are using. Otherwise it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Rather than rolling this yourself, you might wish to consider SQLCipher, which has AES-256 encryption and supports both iOS and Android. http://sqlcipher.net/

Comment: as i understand, sqlcipher crypts after the data are entered?

Comment: owlstead
Well I am interesested in answers for both block mode and operation mode.
Also both plain text and hex would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well say that the length of the plain text is `P` in bytes (say, text in UTF-8 encoding) and `B` is the block size of the underlying cipher and you would use CBC as mode of operation and PKCS#7 padding. In that case you would retrieve the following size of ciphertext in bytes (including a pre-pended IV):

```
C = B + P + B - P % B
```

now to convert those bytes to hexadecimal characters you would simply multiply by 2:

```
H = C * 2
```

So for a single UTF-8 character lower than value `7F` you would get 64 hexadecimal characters.

This is probably not what you were expected. You can switch to counter mode encryption which does not require padding. You could use some other unique number to derive an IV. You could store the ciphertext in binary or base 64 (which only requires one extra character value per 3 bytes). All in all there are too many options to discuss here. If you need to think about this much, it is probably better to keep to build in cryptographic functions.

If you go really far you should look into format preserving encryption, and using alphabets with a size that are not precisely on bit boundaries.

Comment: Anything missing from my answer? It's not possible to answer in more detail without more information.